# Calculating the Logarithm of a Non-Diagonalizable Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

So I've worked through a couple examples which were straight forward.

Matrices like $A = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 4 & 1\\ 0 & e\end{array}\right]$, were easy because $A$ is diagonalizable.

The only non-diagonalizable example we covered in class were of the form

$\lambda I + N$, where $N^r = 0$ for some positive integer $r$, then we used the formula

$\log(\lambda I + N) = \log(\lambda I) + \sum\limits_{n=1}^{r-1}\frac{(-N)^{n}}{j\lambda^{j}}$.

How can you calculate the log if it doesn't fall under one of these two forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Jordan normal form of a complex matrix can be written as a "block diagonal" matrix, where each block on the diagonal is of the form $\lambda I + N$ in your form.  So you can compute the logarithm of each block.  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Complex_matrices and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix#The_logarithm_of_a_non-diagonalizable_matrix.

Answer (score 3):

That's where the Jordan decomposition comes in. Remember that there is always a similarity transformation for a matrix that turns it into a block-diagonal matrix whose diagonal blocks are either scalars or Jordan blocks. Once you have the Jordan decomposition, apply the logarithm formulae you know on the scalar and/or Jordan blocks, and then undo the similarity transformation.

Comment: In practice, however, the Jordan route isn't always the best/most efficient way to compute a matrix logarithm. See [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=S6gpNn1JmbgC&pg=PA269) for instance.

Comment: Well I think this is where my weak background in linear algebra comes in.  I have vaguely heard this result, but don't know the procedure.  If I understand it right, the finding the Jordan normal form of a complex matrix is a generalization of the Diagonalization process.  Any good links to an example of this method explained to someone who's never seen it before?

Comment: You'll want to see [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=PlYQN0ypTwEC&pg=PA119).